# Why pattern regular expression [0-9a-z]{6} not replacing?

Tags: java, regex

Hi What is the problem with this code ?why it is not replacing?

```
String text= new String("0x421256,0x4a1256,0x4a1256,0x4a1256");
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("0x(?=\\[0-9a-z]{6})|(0)x(?=\\[0-9a-z{5})","$1"));
```

output should be `421256,4a1256,4a1256,4a1256`

but it is `0x421256,0x4a1256,0x4a1256,0x4a1256`

Comment: Try this [`System.out.println(text.replaceAll("\\b0x([0-9a-f]{5,6})\\b","$1"));`](https://rextester.com/ZLDA74955)

Comment: @Gurman All hexadecimal replaced should be of 6 digits finally.But here after replacing 5 digits word is also coming.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to replace all occurrences of `0x`?

Comment: @Gurman My assignment demands to replace all hexadecimal digits with 0x if leading characters are of length six else just remove x and retain 0 so as to make total lenth of word  six.